# Pandas, append data based on hierarchy values in columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

Trying to find a suitable pandas code to do this in optimized way (need to deal with millions of rows)

The input dataframe look like

```
    levels value
0      5.1     X
1    5.1.1     Y
2    5.1.1.1   Y1
3    5.1.2     Z
4      5.2     A
5    5.2.2     B
6  5.2.2.1     C
7  5.2.2.2     D
```

and the output dataframe should be like

```
    levels value  newValue
0      5.1     X  X,Y,Y1,Z
1    5.1.1     Y      Y,Y1
2  5.1.1.1    Y1        Y1
3    5.1.2     Z         Z
4      5.2     A   A,B,C,D
5    5.2.2     B     B,C,D
6  5.2.2.1     C         C
7  5.2.2.2     D         D
```

Rules for appending values is, when you see a level, append its value with all sub levels matching '^{level}'. For example, if it is level 5.2.2, then append all rows matching r'^5.2.2*'. If the level is 5.2. then append all rows matching r'^5.2*'
Any advise?

Comment: Show the grouping with regex you used.

Comment: what are the rules for generating newValue?

Comment: Please submit your code that is slow

Comment: Rules for appending values is, when you see a level, append its value with all sub levels matching '^{level}'. For example, if it is level 5.2.2, then append all rows matching r'^5.2.2*'

Comment: Did I answer your question? Should be a relatively straightforward one-liner after rethinking it. Kindly accept the answer as the solution by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the accumulation of the levels. Should work with extended levels, too

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
ml = df.levels.str.len().max()

l = []
for i in range(3, ml+1, 2):
    df1 = df.groupby(df.levels.str[:i])['value'].apply(list)
    l.append(pd.merge(df[['index','levels']], df1, on='levels'))
    df = df[~df.levels.isin(df1.index)]
pd.concat(l).sort_values('index').set_index('index')
```

Output

```
        levels          value
index                        
0          5.1  [X, Y, Y1, Z]
1        5.1.1        [Y, Y1]
2      5.1.1.1           [Y1]
3        5.1.2            [Z]
4          5.2   [A, B, C, D]
5        5.2.2      [B, C, D]
6      5.2.2.1            [C]
7      5.2.2.2            [D]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this one line with list comprehension. Essentially, you can return all `values` into a list, where the `level` is a substring of another row's `level` per row.

```
df['value_list'] = df.apply(lambda x: [z for y,z in zip(df['levels'], df['value']) if x['levels'] in y], axis=1)
df
Out[1]: 
    levels value     value_list
0      5.1     X  [X, Y, Y1, Z]
1    5.1.1     Y        [Y, Y1]
2  5.1.1.1    Y1           [Y1]
3    5.1.2     Z            [Z]
4      5.2     A   [A, B, C, D]
5    5.2.2     B      [B, C, D]
6  5.2.2.1     C            [C]
7  5.2.2.2     D            [D]
```